# .ics Calendar. Appointment Via Email API Emailing Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, icalendar

Hello every one I am creating a system that creates a event like an Appointment.Then it sends it to a receiver via Email using [This method](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html)

It creates a Calendar like this.

```
  string[]  contents = { "BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
                          "PRODID:-//Flo Inc.//FloSoft//EN",
                          "BEGIN:VEVENT",
                          "DTSTART:" + schBeginDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"),
                          "DTEND:" + schEndDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"),
                          "LOCATION:" + schLocation,
                          "ORGANIZER:" + "Haseeb",
                     "DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + schDescription,
                          "SUMMARY:" + schSubject, "PRIORITY:3",
                     "END:VEVENT", "END:VCALENDAR" };

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("Calendar's//" + txtCelenderName.Text + ".ics"),
contents);
```

It works all good and sends Email but every time it creates a Event it downloads a file which is a big data a company with 400 users and meetings with customers is going to be over load. Is there any other method to send Calendar reminders without saving it into a path. 
This is how i send the Attachment.

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "key-key");

RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.AddParameter("domain", "email.com", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFromAlias))
    request.AddParameter("from", sFromAlias + " <" + sFrom + ">");
else
    request.AddParameter("from", "<" + sFrom + ">");

request.AddParameter("subject", sSubject);
request.AddParameter("html", sBody);
request.AddFile("attachment", Path, "text/calendar"); // This is the Celender that goes along the Email 
request.Method = Method.POST;
```

Comment: Don't create ics files yourself. Find a library that handles the nuances for you. And where are you saving the file to a path? You haven't shown that in your question.

Comment: as you can see System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("Calendar's//" + txtCelenderName.Text + ".ics"), contents); << this code writes and saves the File as ics file in a folder called Calendar's.

Comment: Okay. So show your email sending code in the question itself, including how you add the ics file to your email. A link to a 3rd party site isn't sufficient to show this.

Comment: That method is added too.

Comment: Looks like you're using RestSharp. There's a method `RestRequest.AddFileBytes`. Why don't you make use of that? Just convert your string to a byte array and call that method, no need to write an actual file to disc.

Comment: Error converting Sting[] to bytes 20 times tried

Comment: I can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't put the code in your question.

Comment: Ok so i have this `request.AddFileBytes("File.ics",  Calender, "File.ics",  "Calendar/ics");` now the Calendar is the Bytes of that string. its not sending any thing.

Comment: Again, you haven't shown how you're creating the byte array. Please review [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It worked i used this to convert it to byte.  `string fullstring = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, contents);    // Joins all elements in the array together into a single string.
        byte[] arrayofbytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(fullstring);`
Thanks a lot Sir